# Jenkins dashboard Build Executor Status showing more jobs than allowed by the node

Tags: jenkins, build, status, executor

We have a Jenkins master node setup with 0 executors and a number of Windows and Linux slaves, each defined to only run one executor.  We have a matrix build (job_name1 below).  I notice on the Jenkins main dashboard on the left hand side under "Build Executor Status" that under a few of the nodes I see more than one job listed, something like this:

```
Linux_node_1
  job_name1 >> lnx64,build     #15
  job_name1                    #11
  job_name1                    #13

Windows_node_1
  job_name1 >> win32,build     #13
  job_name1                    #15

Windows_node_2
  job_name1 >> win32,build     #11
```

Under each line it shows a status bar.

My question, is it possible to configure this view to only show me what the node is currently running and make other changes to this?  I ask because I find the information confusing.

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

#123 can be exchanged using the "Set Build Name" Plugin:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin